# Convert a Jupyter Notebook into a R studio script

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

Good morning,

I am using Jupyter Notebook but my file has already 9MB and it requires too much time to run it. Given this, I want to use R studio from now on.

I tried to download my notebook as a R file, but when I open it in R studio it does not show any code...

Is there any way of converting the notebook into a script readable in R studio? Or is my procedure correct and the file is only loading (I uploaded it to R studio and I am waiting for more than 45 minutes)?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you might want to use `convert_ipynb` function from `rmarkdown` package.

You use it as:
`convert_ipynb(input, output)`, where `input` is the `.ipynb` file path.

It converts your notebook to a as a `.Rmd` file, which is much easier to deal with.

For more info, check the documentation here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmarkdown/versions/2.6/topics/convert_ipynb

Comment: If you want the file as an R script (`.R`), you can subsequently use `knitr::purl()` to convert the Rmarkdown file. https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/purl.html#purl

Answer (score 2):

As previously posted, if you just want something readable in RStudio, `rmarkdown::convert_ipynb()` will do the trick. This will convert the file into RMarkdown (.Rmd) format. If you want it in pure script format (.R), you can do a secondary step, converting the .Rmd into .R using `knitr::purl()`.

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(xfun)

input <- "/path/to/file.ipynb"

# First convert to .Rmd...
convert_ipynb(input)

# ..then convert .Rmd into .R
purl(with_ext(input, "Rmd"), output = with_ext(input, "R"))

# (Optional) Remove .Rmd file
file.remove(with_ext(input, "Rmd"))
```

---

I wrote a small convenience function that will accomplish the task:

```
convert_ipynb_to_r <- function(
    input, 
    output = xfun::with_ext(input, "R"),
    keep_rmd = FALSE,
    ...
    ) {
        ## Check if necessary packages are installed
        if (!require("rmarkdown")) return("Missing necessary package: 'rmarkdown'")
        if (!require("knitr")) return("Missing necessary package: 'knitr'")

        ## Check if file extension is matches Jupyter notebook.
        if (tolower(xfun::file_ext(input)) != "ipynb") { 
            return( "Error: Invalid file format" )
        }

        ## Conversion process: 
        ## .ipynb to .Rmd
        rmarkdown::convert_ipynb(input)
        ## .Rmd to .R
        knitr::purl(xfun::with_ext(input, "Rmd"), output = output)

        ## Keep or remove intermediary .Rmd
        if (keep_rmd == FALSE) {
            file.remove(xfun::with_ext(input, "Rmd"))
    }
}
```